# how to upload file to users google drive account

Tags: google-drive-api

We have a scenario where we need to upload files from our website to user's google drive account once user approves to do. Out website is deployed in house so not sure how I could push the big file to users google drive account.

Could you please guide me on this.

Thank you

Comment: You could use [Google Drive's API for the browser](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) to achieve this and to use oAuth2 to be able to access and upload these files. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) you can find more information about oAuth2 and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) about how to upload a file with the Drive API. Let me know if this was the kind of information you were looking for or if this has worked for you to formalise it into an answer.

Comment: Do I need enable drive api at my google account ?

Comment: Yes indeed @arc

Comment: Did that work @arc ?

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am yet to try on this. I will update you :)